# Why absolute not working in my html table email project?

Tags: html, css, templates, outlook, html-email

I wanted to add this little border in my email template project. I tried div with position absolute. But when i saw the output in gmail or outlook, position absolute not working. Its breaking the layout. Also is there any way to do this [image]  square borders in html email template

gmail look - [image]

```
Document



<table align="center"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fullwidth" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px;" >

<tr bgcolor="#112369">
 <td align="left" class="pl16 pr16" height="40" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;padding:30px 48px 0px 48px; position: relative;">
  <h1 align="left" style="padding: 5px;  margin: 0px; line-height: 35px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">
   How ACS Time Critical achieves an end-to-end service
  </h1>
  <div style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #00abe6; width: 20px; position: absolute; top: 26%; left: 8%;"></div>
   <div style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #00abe6; width: 20px; position: absolute; top: 35.5%; left: 6%; transform: rotate(90deg);"></div>
   
  </td></tr>
   <tr>
 <td align="center" class="pl16 pr16" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;padding:0px 48px 0px 48px;">
  <div align="left" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;">
  </div></td></tr>
  <tr>
 <td align="center" class="pl16 pr16" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;padding:0px 48px 0px 48px;">
  <div align="left" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;">
  </div></td></tr>
  <tr>
 <td align="center" class="pl16 pr16" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;padding:0px 48px 0px 48px;">
  <div align="left" style="font-size:1px;line-height:1px;">
  </div></td></tr>
  <tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top">
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#112369" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fullwidth" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;" width="640">
   
    <tr>
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#112369" valign="top">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       
        <tr>
         <td class="w16" style="width:48px;" width="48">
          &nbsp;</td><td align="center" valign="top">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           
            <tr>
             <td class="w16 h30" height="48" style="height:30px;">
              &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td class="w16" style="width:48px;" width="48">
          &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr>
     <td align="center" valign="top">
      <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       
        <tr>
         <td align="left" class="w16 h100" style="width: 48px; background-color: rgb(237, 247, 253);" valign="top" width="48">
          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w16 h100" style="width:48px;" width="48">
           
            <tr>
             <td bgcolor="#112369" class="h100" height="75" style="height:75px;">
              &nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
             <td>
              &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td align="center" class="fullwidth heightauto" style="padding-bottom: 0px; background-color: rgb(237, 247, 253);" valign="top">
          <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title=""><img alt=" " data-assetid="40136" src="https://image.acs.aircharterservice.com/lib/fe2f11737364047f721479/m/1/d2642edb-1f46-4d2f-b8af-5609d10b96ca.png" style="display: block; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; color: #000000; max-width: 504px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%;" width="504"></a><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"> </a></td><td align="left" class="w16 h100" style="width: 48px; background-color: rgb(237, 247, 253);" valign="top" width="48">
          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w16 h100" style="width:48px;" width="48">
           
            <tr>
             <td bgcolor="#112369" class="h100" height="75" style="height:75px;">
              &nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
             <td>
              &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Where do you exactly want to add the light-blue border?

Comment: On that exact place like the screen shot. I tried but its not working on gmail , i mean the positioning not working @Qiimiia

Comment: Please also share a screenshot of how the code looks like on gmail

Comment: You can't use `position: absolute` in several email clients. Gmail for sure does not allow it. I don't know any good solution for you though, sorry.

Comment: i shared the screen shot of gmail look of this code. Kindly check in top @Qiimiia

Comment: Is there any other way to do those corner square border in html email template? @RenevandenBerg

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to use a transparent image with the blue part on it, then use that as the background image of the `h1`, positioned at the top left. But I honestly don't know if that will work for every email client.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with different HTML tags/CSS styles to implement the features you want. One way could be adding 2 hr tags:

```
<td ...>
    <hr style="
        height: 2px !important;
        background-color: #00abe6;
        width: 55px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        transform-origin: 0 50%;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        border: none;
    ">


    <hr style="
        height: 2px !important;
        background-color: #00abe6;
        width: 55px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: -2px;
        border: none;
    ">
    <h1...></h1>
</td>
```

Comment: not working on gmail. :( @Qiimiia